# Search a column for specific text, Return value of cell within that row to another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, search, vlookup

I currently manage a warehouse full of tools. Each tool has a specific ID# attached to it, along with a specific location in which it is stored within the warehouse.

To give you an idea of how my tools are being organized, here is a screen shot that I will explain:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiBbV.png)

The first 4 columns are just for organizational purposes. The 5th column is the full tool ID#. The next column is the description of the tool, TOOL ROOM is the main location, and the columns after that specify where in the TOOL ROOM the tool is specifically located.

I would like to create a simple spreadsheet that will search for tools that are located on this spreadsheet in the TOOL ROOM, and return the TOOL ID# to the new spreadsheet. I will then use that same formula to return the description of the tool in a new column on the new spreadsheet.

I researched using VLOOKUP and other formulas, but I can't seem to wrap my brain around specifically how to make this happen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

I have tried VLOOKUP, but I cannot wrap my brain around the specifics of what I am trying to accomplish how that translates to formulas.

I have also seen someone who had a similar issue who apparently got it to work using INDEX & MATCH, but I haven't had luck with that.

Comment: When you say new spreadsheet, do you mean new tab, or a different spreadsheet altogether?

Comment: It's a separate spreadsheet altogether. It's meant for my higher ups to easily see the list of tools without all of the data that I would use.

Comment: Then import the database to a tab on the separate spreadsheet.  Then on a second tab, follow the steps in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not totally achievable with `VLOOKUP` because `VLOOKUP` looks only to the right of the item being searched.  Use `XLOOKUP` instead.  (This also assumes that each tool has a unique name.)

Here are some screenshots of sample data that approximates your data.  Sheet1 is the tool database.

[image: Tool Database]

On Sheet2, I have set up a cell (A1) in the example with the Data Validation option that allows you to select a tool from the list of tools in B2:B on Sheet1.

[image: Data Validation]

Then, using `XLOOKUP`, I have put the formula `=XLOOKUP($A$1,Sheet1!$B$2:$B,Sheet1!A2:A)` in cell A4 on Sheet2.  In this formula in A4, `search_key` is the tool selected from the dropdown in A1, `lookup_range` is the list of tools in B2:B on Sheet1, and `result_range` is the tool ID in A2:A on Sheet1.

[image: First XLOOKUP]

You can then populate any additional columns by using this formula, changing only the `result-range` as needed.

[image: Second XLOOKUP]

Note:  If these are two separate spreadsheets, you can import the tool database to a separate tab of the spreadsheet where you are doing the search using `IMPORTRANGE`.

**Modified Answer Based on Comment**

If you have multiple tools of the same name, you could use the following formula in Sheet2!A4:

=FILTER({Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet1!C2:C,Sheet1!D2:D,Sheet1!E2:E},Sheet1!B2:B=$A$1)

This will return the whole range where the name in the tool column matches the value in Sheet2!A1.

[image: Filter Screenshot]

Comment: This is awesome! Let me test this out really fast on my new spreadsheet, and I will come back shortly and let you know how it worked out!

Comment: Have you had a chance to test this yet?

Comment: Okay, so I ran into an issue. I got it to work, however... I am attempting to import the tools that are located in the TOOL ROOM, and it will definitely find the first tool in the TOOL ROOM, but then any tool after that I get the "#N/A" error sign that says, "Array arguments to XLOOKUP are of different size."

Comment: So the first formula I used that worked was =XLOOKUP($B$4:$C$4,'TOTAL TOOLS'!$I$9:$I,'TOTAL TOOLS'!F9:F) in the next cell down, I don't think the formula accounts for the fact that I have multiple tools in the TOOL ROOM

Comment: Can you share the spreadsheet?

Comment: So I did a little bit more digging, and apparently XLOOKUP stops after it finds the first match. I was hoping to have something that finds multiple matches, and sends them all over to the new sheet row by row until they no longer match. I saw an article that mentions using INDEX, SMALL & ROW functions to accomplish this, so I am currently trying to fart around with that and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Do you have multiple tools with the same name?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple tools of the same type and they are distinguished by the TOOL ID#. I have over 2000 tools that are stored in different locations, so I was hoping to be able to use this function to make a list of just the tools in the TOOL ROOM or in the CONEX, etc.

Comment: I have modified my answer based on your comment.  This should work as long as the tool names are exactly the same.

Comment: I FINALLY GOT IT TO DO WHAT I NEED IT TO DO, I USED THE FUNCTION =FILTER('TOTAL TOOLS'!F9:F,'TOTAL TOOLS'!I9:I=B4)

Comment: Glad you got it working.